# How can i get both sender and receivers mobile number in Android

Tags: java, android, sms

I tried finding current mobile no of my app user but in my country the mobile no is not present in SIM so the current API returns null.

As a work around i thought i would just access the outbox of the user to get both senders and receivers no but unfortunately i am getting only receivers no.

Say for example I am user X and I send an SMS to user Y, through telephony API i am only able to get phone no of user Y to whom i am sending the SMS but not of user X.

Can any one suggest any other way i can access the current mobile no of any user??

Thanks
Pranay

Answer (score 0):

Do you think this is what you are looking for? [TelephonyManager::getLine1Number](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getLine1Number%28%29)

(please, notice you are going to need the "android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" permission set in your app manifest.)